# How do I specify encoding in scikit-learn OrdinalEncoder?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data, encoding

Scikit-learn object OrdinalEncoder() allows the user to create a lineary based encoding principle for ordinal data, however the the codes are encoded randomly. Is there any way I can specify how the encoding will be done?

For example based on a simple python dictionary key : value pair:

```
difficulty = {
  "easy" : 1,
  "medium" : 2,
  "hard" : 3
}
```

Comment: You could use something like `enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[[None, "easy", "medium", "hard"]], dtype=np.int8)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out

Answer (score 2):

OrdinalEncoder can accept categorical value mapping during initiation.

Something like this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[[None, "easy", "medium", "hard"]])
X = [["easy"], ["easy"], ["hard"], ["medium"]]
X_encoded = enc.fit_transform(X)
```